# SFML 2.0 - Drawing a starfield

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, sfml

I'm using sfml 2.0 to make a game. The background is going to be a starfield. Rather than use an image, I thought it might be neat to randomly generate a starfield each time the game starts up, so the background looks *slightly* different each time. Problem is, the way I'm currently doing it slows my game down A LOT. Does anyone know what is causing the speed hit? I've looked through the documentation to see what, but I haven't found anything...

Here's my code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "sfml helper/initialization_helpers.h"
#include "sfml helper/cursor_functions.h"
#include "sfml helper/global_event_handler.h"
#include "sfml helper/globals.h"
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try {
        // some non-related preparations...
        PrepareApplication(argv[0]);
        float width = 640, height = 480;
        sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(width, height), "SFML Test", sf::Style::Close);
        window.setFramerateLimit(60);

        // Textures is a global object that has an internal std::map<string, sf::Texture>
        Textures.add("ball.png", "ball");
        sf::Sprite sprite;
        sprite.setTexture(Textures.get("ball"));

        // This is the snippet that generates the starfield
        srand(time(NULL));
        sf::Image starsImg;
        starsImg.create(width, height, sf::Color::Black);
        int numStars = rand() % 20 + 490;
        for (int i = 0; i < numStars; i++) {
            int x = rand() % (int)width;
            int y = rand() % (int)height;
            sf::Color color(255, 255, 255, rand() % 75 + 25);
            starsImg.setPixel(x, y, color);
        }
        sf::Texture starsTexture;
        starsTexture.loadFromImage(starsImg);
        sf::Sprite stars;
        stars.setTexture(starsTexture);

        // main loop
        while (window.isOpen()) {
            if (Flags.isActive && Flags.inFocus) {
                confineCursorToWindow(window);
            } else {
                freeCursor();
            }
            sf::Event event;
            while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
                    if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) {
                        Flags.isActive = (!Flags.isActive);
                    }
                }
                if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseMoved) {
                    sprite.setPosition(event.mouseMove.x, event.mouseMove.y);
               }
                // handles default events like sf::Event::WindowClosed
                handleDefaultEventsForWindow(event, window);
            }
            window.clear();
            window.draw(stars); // here's where I draw the stars
            window.draw(sprite);
            window.display();
        }
    } catch (const char* error) {
        printf("%s\n", error);
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

I tried loading an image of a starfield and tried drawing that, the game still runs slow!

Also, by slow, I mean the sprite called "sprite" lags when following the mouse. Is that *actually* a speed issue?

Comment: Are you sure you are only generating the star-field when the game starts, and not every frame?

Comment: it's outside the `while (window.isOpened) { ... }` loop, so it shoud be...

However, I'll post the FULL code for better inspection

Comment: Have you tried creating a RenderWindow and drawing your Texture directly? It's probably not the cause of your problem but I see Image->Texture->Sprite as an overhead; and RenderWindow is nicer too when you're working with textures and stuff.

Comment: I was able to run the star generation perfectly fine by itself. You should look to see if something else is holding the program back by using a profiler.